# Remove accented characters, don't replace them

Tags: r, regex, gsub

there's a lot of people asking how to remove accents from data, but I'm looking for how to remove the entire character. They're retained using [[:alnum:]], and [[A-Za-z]]. What would I have to do to get rid of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do in `base` R:

```
gsub("[^A-Za-z ]", "", "à la volée d'où est-il")
[1] " la vole do estil"
```

Here exclude everything that is not letters and spaces. Have a look if you want to keep punctuation with `[:punct:]`

Answer (score 0):

Without using regex, you could define a set of letters you would accept, which is available in base R as the `letters` and `LETTERS` vectors.

```
characters_to_keep <- c(letters, " ")
accentstring <- "éqodio diq ozàoih"
result <- unlist(strsplit(accentstring,""))
result <- result[result %in% characters_to_keep]
result <- paste0(result, collapse="")
> result
[1] "qodio diq ozoih"
```

Comment: Thanks, that should work fine. How do I also retain spaces doing it this way?